# How to combine dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, intersect

I'd like to combine two dataframe in a new one which contain columns from both of them, moreover I need to put in the new dataframe only rows with same id.

my dataframes looks like:

```
df1
Name       V1  V2   V3
str1       .   .    strA    
str2       .   .    strB
..         .   . 
str16000   .   .    strC


df2
Name       V1  V2   V3
str2       .   .    strD    
str1       .   .    strE
..         .   . 
str20000   .   .    strF
```

I'd like an output like:

```
Name     df1$v3    df2$v3
str1     strA      strE
str2     strB      strD
```

Note that df1 and df2 have different lenghts, moreover the same item in df1 and df2 has not the same position.

thanks you guys

Comment: How about `innerjoin` `library(dplyr); inner_join(df1[c("Name", "V3")], df2[c("Name", "V3")], by = "Name")`  or use `merge` from `base R`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I combine two dataframes with different lengths in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257572/how-can-i-combine-two-dataframes-with-different-lengths-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **merge** function

```
lines=
   'Name      V1  V2   V3
    str1      NA  NA   strA    
    str2      NA  NA   strB
    str16000  NA  NA   strC'

df1 = read.table(textConnection(lines), header = T)

lines=
   'Name      V1  V2   V3
    str1      NA  NA   strD    
    str2      NA  NA   strE
    str16000  NA  NA   strF'

df2 = read.table(textConnection(lines), header = T)


dfnew = merge(df1[1:2, -2:-3], df2[1:2, -2:-3], by='Name')

colnames(dfnew) = c('Name', 'df1$v3 ', 'df2$v3')

dfnew 

#  Name df1$v3  df2$v3
#1 str1    strA   strD
#2 str2    strB   strE
```